# How to explain temporal fluctuations in pinging to Google with router?

Tags: networking, router, google-search

I experience 2-5x slower ping times when connecting to the internet through my router than without it. 
The fluctuations can be very short like delta function, and very long like respiratory wave. 
I am living in a big student housing so significant download processes may occur of other students, but I am still surprised by such massive temporal events, because they have not occurred in two years living in the place. 
Getting the internet directly from wall is much faster. 
I went through all my settings of my router but could not find any explanation. 
Things done

- I switched all cables so individual cables should not be a problem.
- I shortened the RJ45 cables much in the network, to minimise any cable damage or to minimise the effect of total distance of RJ45 cables on network speed.
- I turned off 2.5 GHz wifi channel, only 5 GHz now. It improved the mininum time to reach Google from 4 ms to 2 ms on average.
- I halved the amount of electric cables in my network.

Other answers

1. There is no performance change between with cable to router vs wifi.
2. I have tested on 7 different systems.
3. I have disabled all parts of V6, only V4.
4. I am using ip address of ISP which is changing.
5. Some other students in the some corridor experience the same problem in ping times. It started yesterday and has continued so far.

### Example ping times without router

```
PING google.com (159....) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=2.20 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=1.85 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=2.10 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=2.49 ms
...
```

Traceroute without router

```
root@masi:/etc/openvpn# tracepath google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  10.10.10.1                                            0.936ms 
 1:  10.10.10.1                                            0.751ms 
 2:  83.241.95.1                                           1.986ms 
 3:  vl548-opt.sw4.riga2.nano.lv                           1.846ms 
 4:  91.203.69.93                                          2.130ms 
 5:  159.148.79.58                                         1.812ms 
 6:  titan-gw.v3000.latnetserviss.lv                       2.636ms 
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

### Short fluctuations with router

```
masi@masi:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (159....) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1159 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=168 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=1187 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=196 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=1711 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=710 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=1666 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=666 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=2765 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=10 ttl=57 time=1766 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=11 ttl=57 time=766 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=12 ttl=57 time=1578 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=13 ttl=57 time=578 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 15 received, 11% packet loss, time 18711ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 168.450/1140.935/2765.809/684.821 ms, pipe 3
```

Traceroute with router

```
root@masi:/etc/openvpn# tracepath google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           5.763ms 
 1:  192.168.1.1                                           2.984ms 
 2:  10.10.10.1                                           15.920ms 
 3:  83.241.95.1                                          21.458ms 
 4:  vl548-opt.sw4.riga2.nano.lv                         256.015ms 
 5:  91.203.69.93                                        251.707ms 
 6:  159.148.79.58                                        84.024ms 
 7:  titan-gw.v3000.latnetserviss.lv                       8.012ms 
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

### Long fluctuations with router

```
 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=3.76 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=5.78 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=7.70 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=5.40 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=10 ttl=57 time=8.10 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=11 ttl=57 time=6.99 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=12 ttl=57 time=5.99 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=13 ttl=57 time=4.96 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159....): icmp_seq=14 ttl=57 time=7.77 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=15 ttl=57 time=1002 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=16 ttl=57 time=430 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=17 ttl=57 time=290 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=18 ttl=57 time=273 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=19 ttl=57 time=228 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=20 ttl=57 time=183 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=21 ttl=57 time=238 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=22 ttl=57 time=121 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=23 ttl=57 time=1732 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=24 ttl=57 time=732 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=25 ttl=57 time=400 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=26 ttl=57 time=912 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=27 ttl=57 time=772 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=28 ttl=57 time=272 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=29 ttl=57 time=355 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=30 ttl=57 time=6.99 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=31 ttl=57 time=5.96 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=32 ttl=57 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=33 ttl=57 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=34 ttl=57 time=87.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=35 ttl=57 time=6.93 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=36 ttl=57 time=384 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=37 ttl=57 time=157 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=38 ttl=57 time=20.0 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=39 ttl=57 time=7.00 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=40 ttl=57 time=5.72 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=41 ttl=57 time=175 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=42 ttl=57 time=138 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=43 ttl=57 time=336 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=44 ttl=57 time=305 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=45 ttl=57 time=264 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
46 packets transmitted, 45 received, 2% packet loss, time 45056ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.358/221.338/1732.050/337.887 ms, pipe 2
```

### Pinging to Google with VPN and router

Connect to NordVPN Finland first server. 
The minimum time is little greater than in others but the stability seems to be better than in other behind router.

```
masi@masi:/etc/openvpn$ ping google.com
PING google.com (159....) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1591 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=2200 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=1503 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=2251 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=1798 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=850 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=1618 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=640 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=47.4 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=49.8 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=43.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=46.2 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=44.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=44.9 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=47.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=53.8 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=51.0 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=44.5 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=42.8 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=48.5 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=43.1 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=42.2 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=41.0 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=26 ttl=56 time=43.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=27 ttl=56 time=45.7 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=28 ttl=56 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=29 ttl=56 time=41.9 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=30 ttl=56 time=204 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=31 ttl=56 time=211 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=32 ttl=56 time=182 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=33 ttl=56 time=265 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=34 ttl=56 time=239 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=35 ttl=56 time=206 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=36 ttl=56 time=378 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=37 ttl=56 time=215 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (159...): icmp_seq=38 ttl=56 time=194 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
38 packets transmitted, 38 received, 0% packet loss, time 37465ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.088/408.446/2251.809/647.256 ms, pipe 3
```

My proposals

- ISP sniffing because I have lost also before packages when not behind VPN here.
- Other students sniffing. My passwords are very strong, but only one-side protection, no two-step password so a weakness.

Router: TP-Link MR200 (used as router)
Clients: Asus Zenbook UX303UA, Acer Chromebook 2, Asus 2013 i7 PC, Dell PCs, Lenovo laptop, Onelplus two
OS in clients: Debian 8.5 64 bit, Chromebook, Oxygen OS 3.1
Internet protocol: IPV4 (IPV6 in no device and no tunnelling)

Comment: You talked about wifi and cables. Can you turn off wi-fi and see if there is a performance chance for just cable.  Then compare to wifi. (2) Have you tested with different devices and different architectures?  Ie - 2+ laptops with different OS, smart phone, tablet.  (3) have you tried a tracert to make sure path is the same both times? (4)have you tried the raw ip address to drop DNS out of the test (5) It looks like you are using TCPIP V4, have you gone into the router and disabled all parts of V6?

Comment: I have you run a speed test? If so and difference? Have you checked with others students to see what they report as normal ping times?

Comment: @bvaughn I answered your questions in the body. Now, doing speedtests.

Comment: Excellent, the "Some other students in the some corridor experience the same problem in ping times. It started yesterday and has continued so far. " indicates it will not be with your setup. Most likely it will take the University IT department's involvement to understand the issue and fix it.  IT could be as simple as a switch on your floor needs replaced. Or there could be a new security appliance, a change in AD, or other change/issue.